# Google Maps Embed Advanced API

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-embed

So. Google is changing the Maps API and there's now a difference between Embed Maps and Embed Advanced Maps.

Could anyone tell me the difference between an embed map and an advanced embed map?

The potential charges are huge if I'm mistaken here.

For those of you who don't know, Google is some of its APIs including maps, geocoding, and places:

- https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/
- https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this a little vague, too. The answer seems to have been found here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/27FsQgTd8j0/ArdG7QROAgAJ

"Essentially, Embed with Dynamic Maps or a map with a marker, will continue to be free with unlimited usage. Embed API requests using Directions mode, View mode, or Search mode will now be billed. See the pricing table for details."

That had me worried. As a lazy web designer, I'd been using my own credentials to add maps to client sites. Looks like I'm still in the free tier.

Comment: What is the difference between "Embed with Dynamic Maps" and "map with a marker"?

Comment: I can't work this out. I'm only using an embedded map with a marker and I've been hit with a £300 bill for the month.

Answer (score 2):

**Embed Advanced** map lets you place an interactive frame with the map on your site with simple HTML (by adding URL). Except for marking the place with the pin you can also show on it the street view, routes or insert a search field.

**Embed map** lets you place an interactive map frame on your site with simple HTML (by adding URL). You can put a single marker on it.

If you're not sure which option you're in, [this website](https://www.globema.com/short-guide-understanding-google-maps-platform-products-maps/) helped me.